# GridLayout android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have GridLayout as child view, with set (empty) GridLayout.LayoutParams

```
setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams());
```

I do not set LayoutParams to this anywhere else. But I'm getting exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$LayoutParams
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.computeLayoutParamsHashCode(GridLayout.java:872)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.checkForLayoutParamsModification(GridLayout.java:879)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:927)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1249)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  304):   Force finishing activity com.capsule.launcher/.LauncherActivity
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Android Api your app uses? Looks like it uses Api 14 or above and You also use android support library. Error described in question is possible when you try to pass `GridLayout.LayoutParams()` from Api 14 to `GridLayout.setLayoutParams` from support library. Please, check your imports.

Comment: I'm building for 2.3.3 and using latest support library.

Comment: import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;

Answer (score 3):

Are you passing a `GridLayout.LayoutParams` to the `GridLayout` itself? I don't believe that's right.

When you call `setLayoutParams`, you're providing information to the parent class about how to layout the particular child. You should pass a `<ParentClass>.LayoutParams` to the GridLayout, where `ParentClass` is whatever container the GridLayout is in.

`GridLayout.LayoutParams` is only for setting the layoutParams for the *children* of a `GridLayout`.